# Add google analytics to an existing site created with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, google-analytics

Firstly I'm not a web developer!  My site was created by a company that is no longer in business, so I have access to the admin page to add content, but know nothing about the back end.

I have been asked by an SEO company to add Google analytics, when I tried to add the script.../script  to my footer, which is included in all pages, it shows up in the page source of a web browser, but does not run, and Google tells me it's not installed.

Is there a way to add either a script to via the admin tool, or a < ?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

If the latter, into which directory should I ftp the analyticstracking.php file?

Comment: analyticstracking.php should be in the same folder as the file that should be reading from it.   Have you tried to view the source of the page to be sure that it is infact being added?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it shows up in the page source, you are halfway there. You just probably did not copy-paste it right. Try copying the EXACT code in google analytics, put it in the footer and try again.

The include functions won't do anything different than putting the code straight in the footer.

Note that you need to have some visits on the site so that GA knows the script is installed.

Comment: if i just change the fomatting , does it change anything . I mean as coders ourselves , we know it shouldn't?